# printing in xcode is different in terminal for tcp/ip connection

Tags: c, xcode, sockets, unix, tcp

I am writing a tcp/ip client program that accepts string (the game ui) from a server in C (not c++)
and gives a move back to the server.

The server send the string one by one, ie

```
        message = "Not won yet!\n";
        write(sock , message , strlen(message));


        message = "My move is...\n";
        write(sock , message , strlen(message));
```

my client code

```
char read_buffer[MAX_BUFFER];
char send_buffer[MAX_BUFFER];

int num;


recv(sockfd , read_buffer , MAX_BUFFER , 0);
printf("%s",read_buffer);
recv(sockfd , read_buffer , MAX_BUFFER , 0);
printf("%s",read_buffer);
while(1)
{


    scanf("%s" , send_buffer);

    //Send some data
    if( send(sockfd , send_buffer , strlen(send_buffer) , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("Send failed");
        break;
    }

    //Receive a reply from the server

    if( recv(sockfd , read_buffer , MAX_BUFFER , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("recv failed");
        break;
    }

    //puts("Server reply :");
    printf("%s",read_buffer);
}
```

In xcode i can get a full output

but in terminal i get (output seemed staggered)

```
Enter column number: 
3

nter column number: 
4
| 5

| 3
 I play in column 5
3
```

I can't post images i'll try to find a way but if someone can give one rep up then I can post the image.

Main Question
:- How should I code my client so that it receives all the messages then print it properly.
:- What should I do to get the full output ?

---

SOLUTION =
Debug and see what is inside your buffer.
Apparently the buffer has all the content already as the comment pointed out (thanks to not listening to lecture)

But during printing, the buffer contains many "\0" (sentienel that is cause undefined behaviour) (actually it stops at the first sentienel) causing my output to go wayhire.

Solution print the char one by one :)

Comment: TCP is a streaming protocol, with no real packets or message boundaries. You might have to receive multiple times to receive a single message. Or you might receive multiple messages in a single receive call. You have to think about that when modelling your own protocol above TCP.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg but in my code, I need to use multiple receive to get two messages. Is it possible to use one single receive to get all the messages. then realize that the server is waiting for input, then send and input and repeat the loop again ?

Comment: I have checked, that the buffer has all the messages that I wanted,
terminal doesn't print properly,xcode does :( ?

Comment: There is one major problem though... You don't terminate the buffer after you read into it. All strings needs to have a special character as terminator. If the string is not terminated, then printing it with `printf` can lead to `printf` continuing to print characters even after the end of the buffer, and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You are right, if you can put your comment as answer I can put it as the answer. @JoachimPileborg